# Index arguments in zsh

Tags: arguments, zsh

With zsh I can get the fifth argument simply with `$5`. But what if `5` is a variable? I've come up with this way to print out the first five arguments by indexing (as opposed to just `echo $1 $2 $3 $4 $5`):

```
for i in {1..5}
do
  echo $(eval echo "\$$i")
done
```

But surely there must be a better way?

---

I know that there is much simpler ways to loop through all arguments. In my particular case I want to loop through the argument list backward. Help with that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate through the positional parameters, just use a for loop:

```
for x; do echo $x; done
```

To iterate through them in reverse:

```
for x in "${(Oa)@}"; do echo $x ; done
```

To reverse the parameters:

```
set "${(Oa)@}"
```

Comment: What does `(0a)` mean? Is it zsh specific?

Comment: (Oa) is very much zsh specific.  (It is the letter 0, not the number 0).  The `O` means sort in descending order.  The `a` means to use the array index as the sort key.  `man zshall` for details.

Comment: Thank you very much. For others, `man zshexpn` gives the relevant manual chapters, explaining both `O` and `a`.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh (and zsh only, [apparently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12087)) the `@` is an array. Practically you can use it like this:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
  echo $@[i]
done
```

---

As for looping backwards I guess you can combine `for i in {$#..1}` with `$@[i]` but there might be a better way.